# Not able to find builder for capability: TokenServiceCapability

Tags: web8.5, installation, microservices, discovery-service

I have installed the micro-services successfully and they are up and running. But, when I run the registration jar file to register all the services with the discovery service, I get an error saying "Not able to find builder for capability: TokenServiceCapability"

The command I am running is java -jar discovery-registration.jar update from the discovery config folder as mentioned in the SDL docs.

Here is a screenshot of the error
[image]

There is nothing in the logs too.

Also, this is what I have in the cd_storage_conf.xml file in the discovery/config folder

```
<ConfigRepository CacheEnabled="true" CacheExpirationDuration="600" ClientId="registration" ClientSecret="encrypted:HzfQh9wYwAKShDxCm4DnnBnysAz9PtbDMFXMbPszSVY=" ConnectionTimeout="40000" ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10" ServiceUri="http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc" TokenServiceUrl="http://localhost:8082/token.svc">
        <Roles>
            <Role Name="TokenServiceCapability" Url="http://localhost:8082/token.svc"/>
            <Role Name="WebCapability"/>
        </Roles>
    </ConfigRepository>
```

The microservices are on the same server as the CM, that is why I am using localhost there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was I had Java 9 installed and Web 8.5 only supports Java 8. Just removed Java 9 and installed Java 8 and it worked fine.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Yes. It seems I can accept it only after 2 days.